# How to specify that template parameter is a class template, and infer its template type from another template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider a template function:

```
template <typename OutputContainerType, typename ContainerType>
static OutputContainerType processContainer(ContainerType c)
{
    OutputContainerType result;
    ...
    return result;
}
```

I can call it no problem like so:

```
std::vector<MyClass> v;
const auto result = processContainer<std::set<MyClass>>(v);
```

However, I know that the function will accept and produce different containers, but always with the same element type. So having to specify `std::set<MyClass>>` is redundant; I want to type `processContainer<std::set>(v)` and have the function infer the item type as `decltype(v)::value_type`. How can I do that? I've tried different things like

```
template <template<> class OutputContainerType, class ContainerType>
static OutputContainerType<typename ContainerType::value_type> processContainer(ContainerType c) {}
```

but can't get it to compile no matter what (my understanding of C++ template syntax and tricks is not very deep, as you can see).

Comment: [Template template parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter)

Comment: @chris: thank you. Looks like putting `template<typename> class` instead of `template <> class` solves the problem, but the fact that std containers have 2 template parameters, the second being allocator, makes implementing my idea impossible.

Comment: You can put as many as you need in there, including a parameter pack.

Comment: @chris: yes, of course. But I don't know how to handle the default allocator properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the allocator, you can just omit it:

```
template <template<typename...> class OutputContainerType, template<typename...> class ContainerType, typename ValueType>
static OutputContainerType<ValueType> processContainer(ContainerType<ValueType> c)
{
    OutputContainerType<ValueType> result;
    //  ...
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::set<int> s {1, 2, 3};
    auto v = processContainer<std::vector, std::set, int>(s);
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1409f9e8553adf9b)

Comment: You're right, with template parameters pack it does work (but not with `template<typename>`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
template<template<typename...> class OutputContainerType,
         typename InputContainerType>
static OutputContainerType<typename InputContainerType::value_type>
processContainer(InputContainerType c)
{
    using ValueType = typename InputContainerType::value_type;
    OutputContainerType<ValueType> result;
    //  ...
    return result;
}
```

You might also consider using `const InputContainerType& c` for the parameter to avoid copying the input container.