# Error passing std::vector as a template template parameter - works in GCC, fails in MSVC

Tags: c++, templates

The following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>

#define BEGIN_TO_END(container) container.begin(), container.end()

template <template<typename...> class OutputContainerType, class InContainer>
OutputContainerType<typename InContainer::value_type> convertContainer(const InContainer& in)
{
    OutputContainerType<typename InContainer::value_type> result;
    std::transform(BEGIN_TO_END(in), std::back_inserter(result), [](typename InContainer::value_type value) {return value;});
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::deque<int> d {1, 2, 3};
    const auto v = convertContainer<std::vector>(d);
    std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
}
```

works fine with GCC ([link](https://ideone.com/4k4qrB)). However, it doesn't compile with MSVC 2013 (12.0) with the error: `'std::vector' : class has no constructors` (can be tested [here](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/), select 12.0 compiler version). What's the problem here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: No problem. Just that MSVC, as usual, has bug in this case.

Comment: @Nawaz: it's hard to believe something as basic as a template template parameter would not be covered by the compiler tests. Or is it caused by how `std::vector` is defined?..

Comment: Btw. BEGIN_TO_END can be resolved by Boost.Range: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/transform.html. Using a macro isn't a good style.

Comment: @sfrehse: I don't use boost in my projects. Macros should generally be avoided, but they have a specific place where they can help improve the code and do things impossible without preprocessor. This is one of such cases.

Comment: Curious, is that supposed to work? If I write template <class OutputContainerType, class InContainer> and use std::vector<int> for the output type in the call in main, it compiles OK.

Comment: @Robinson: yes, it is supposed to work, it's  called a template template parameter. See my question from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079331/how-to-specify-that-template-parameter-is-a-class-template-and-infer-its-templa

Comment: Yes you're right.  I tried this and your other question's answer code and neither compiles with MSVC 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>

#define BEGIN_TO_END(container) container.begin(), container.end()

template <template<typename T, typename T2> class OutputContainerType, class InContainer>
OutputContainerType<typename InContainer::value_type, std::allocator<typename InContainer::value_type>> convertContainer(const InContainer& in)
{
    OutputContainerType<typename InContainer::value_type, std::allocator<typename InContainer::value_type>> result;
    std::transform(BEGIN_TO_END(in), std::back_inserter(result), [](typename InContainer::value_type value) {return value;});
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::deque<int> d {1, 2, 3};
    const auto v = convertContainer<std::vector>(d);
    std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Worked. The problem is then with variadic number of template parameters here...

*EDITED:*
Actually not with the variadic number of template parameters as I can even compile it with the

```
template <template<typename...> class OutputContainerType, class InContainer>
```

so the MSVC compiler needs explicitly given each type of the template.

Comment: Thanks! The problem seems to be with the default template parameter then.