# Default template arguments when using template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, emscripten

The following code compiles using gcc 5.2, gcc 4.9, and clang 3.7 at C++11 standard:

```
template <typename T, typename U, template<typename...> class M>
U * find_item(M<T, U> & m, const T & t) {
  auto it = m.find(t);
  if (it != m.end()) { return &it->second; }
  return nullptr;
}

template <typename T, typename U, template<typename...> class M>
const U * find_item(const M<T, U> & m, const T & t) {
  auto it = m.find(t);
  if (it != m.end()) { return &it->second; }
  return nullptr;
}

#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::map<std::string, int> foo;

  foo["asdf"] = 5;
  if (find_item(foo, std::string{"bar"})) { std::cerr << "hmm\n"; }
}
```

However, when I compile it with the latest version of emscripten, I get a compiler error stemming from `too few arguments for class template 'map'`:

```
main.cpp:24:7: error: no matching function for call to 'find_item'
  if (find_item(foo, std::string{"bar"})) { std::cerr << "hmm\n"; }
      ^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:2:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T =
      std::__1::basic_string<char>, U = int, M = map]: too few template
      arguments for class template 'map'
U * find_item(M<T, U> & m, const T & t) {
    ^         ~
main.cpp:9:11: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T =
      std::__1::basic_string<char>, U = int, M = map]: too few template
      arguments for class template 'map'
const U * find_item(const M<T, U> & m, const T & t) {
          ^               ~
1 error generated.
ERROR:root:compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
```

This is a bit odd because my emscripten claims to be based on clang-3.7. Regardless, it seems to have difficulty deducing the default parameters while instantiating the `find_item` template.

If the code is changed in the following way, then all compilers seem to be happy with it:

```
template <typename T, typename U, template<typename...> class M, typename... dummy>
U * find_item(M<T, U, dummy...> & m, const T & t) {
  auto it = m.find(t);
  if (it != m.end()) { return &it->second; }
  return nullptr;
}

template <typename T, typename U, template<typename...> class M, typename... dummy>
const U * find_item(const M<T, U, dummy...> & m, const T & t) {
  auto it = m.find(t);
  if (it != m.end()) { return &it->second; }
  return nullptr;
}

#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::map<std::string, int> foo;

  foo["asdf"] = 5;
  if (find_item(foo, std::string{"bar"})) { std::cerr << "hmm\n"; }
}
```

The question is, should the "dummy" part actually be necessary according to the C++11 standard, or is emscripten defective in not figuring out the default template parameters here?

My reading of section `[temp.deduct.type] 14.8.2.6.8` is that it should be able to bind `std::map` to a template template parameter of the form `M<T, U>` because of the wording "at least one" in this sentence:

> Similarly, <T> represents template argument
>   lists where at least one argument contains a T

But, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: This is [CWG 2057](http://wg21.link/CWG2057).

Comment: I think you are right -- I guess that means it's considered to be underspecified here? Would accept this as the answer.

Comment: MSVC has the [same issues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29097979/27678)

Answer (score 1):

I hit this problem and found that I didn't need the dummy template parameter, specifying the template template as variadic was enough (this is on clang 3.6):

```
template <typename T, typename U, template<typename...> class M>
U * find_item(M<T, U> & m, const T & t) {
  auto it = m.find(t);
  if (it != m.end()) { return &it->second; }
  return nullptr;
}

template <typename T, typename U, template<typename...> class M>
const U * find_item(const M<T, U> & m, const T & t) {
  auto it = m.find(t);
  if (it != m.end()) { return &it->second; }
  return nullptr;
}
```